# html button and javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Ok. I make a program for calculating the power of 2. I have the html code . But i describe it for you first. There is one input with id='inputin' and below there is a button. In the input you write a number . This number will be the exponent of two and after you push the button it appears a console.log window with the result

here the html :

```
<div id='main'>
    <input type="number" name="power2" placeholder='Enter the power' id='inputin'><br/>
    <button id="submit" onclick="binaryS()">Do it!</button>

    </div>
```

and the javascript:

```
binaryS = function() {
x = document.getElementById("inputin").value;
y=1;
for(i=1;i<=x;i++) {
    y=y*2;
}
console.log (y);
};
```

Why it doesnt work? Any help? and if you could suggest instead of an ugly console.log window how can i appear it in a new div somewhere in the page? Thnx

Comment: I'd use `alert(y)` for a quick check (nothing fancy)

Comment: Won't you get same answer for Y every single time as Y = 1?

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a9FrL/

Comment: Seems to work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/rcVrV/

Comment: Do you understand that `console.log()` doesn't open a window automatically? You have to view the log manually using Developer Tools.

Comment: but 0 to the power of 2 isn't 1....or any negative number will break this.

Answer (score 7):

Your JavaScript should be:

```
function binaryS() {
   var x = document.getElementById("inputin").value;
   document.getElementById("outputValue").innerHTML = Math.pow(2,x);
}
```

Place the following somewhere on your page for the display:

```
<div id="outputValue">Result</div>
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it when I was building [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/rcVrV/2/), which does essentially the same, only with `span` and `innerText`. And without using `math`. :p

Comment: That's my first real answer :D Thanks to this lovely site i rarely have questions to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function nearestPow2(){
  return Math.pow(2, Math.round(Math.log(document.getElementById("inputin").value;) / Math.log(2))); 
}
```

Ref: http://weblog.bocoup.com/find-the-closest-power-of-2-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into details, your code is working. I have made a single html page to demonstrate it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/x-javascript">
            binaryS = function() {
                x = document.getElementById("inputin").value;
                y=1;
                for(i=1;i<=x;i++) {
                    y=y*2;
                }
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = y
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='main'>
            <input type="number" name="power2" placeholder='Enter the power' id='inputin'><br/>
            <button id="submit" onclick="binaryS()">Do it!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="result" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also would suggest you using Math.pow instead of a custom math calculation:

```
Math.pow( 2, parseInt(document.getElementById("inputin").value));
```